# Google Analytics tracking clicks in tableView IOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics and trying to implement a track-event when a user clicks in a tableView in my IOS app. What I am trying to track is the name of the "cell" being clicked in the tableView by the user. I am doing something wrong, or rather what steps do I have to make in order to make it work? I can't see any tracks of the event with the code implemented in this example:

Do I have to make any adjustments in my GA to track this? Where is the info supposed to be tracked? I am confused :S /Regards

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellName = @"";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil; 

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cellName = @"BookCell";
        cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
        UILabel *bookField = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        bookField.text = [self getCurrentBookName];

        [self.tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"App Setting"
                            withAction:@"User selects book:"
                             withLabel:self.getCurrentBookName
                             withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine, what the error info ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but where in the GA portal do you find this tracking info? Do you have to set something up by yourself ? I am also tracking Views and they appear by themselves.

Comment: Make sure which value you are using in code that should be match with Category, Action, Label on GA account where you made goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you initializing your tracker? See the Google Analytics Getting Started guide [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/).

You should have something like this in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
// Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;
// Create tracker instance.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"];
```

Then wherever you want to send an event, do the following:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"App Setting"
                    withAction:@"User selects book:"
                     withLabel:self.getCurrentBookName
                     withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

Or, if your class inherits from `GAITrackedViewController`:

```
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[self.tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"App Setting"
                         withAction:@"User selects book:"
                          withLabel:self.getCurrentBookName
                          withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

(And remember `#import "GAI.h"` if your class does not inherit from `GAITrackedViewController`.)

To view the events in Google Analytics:

1. Go to Engagement > Events > Top Events
2. Select the Event Category (in your case, "App Setting")
3. Select the Event Action from the list (in your case, "User selects book:")
4. You now have a list of Event Labels (in your case, book names)

**Note:** It can take up to 24 hours for events to show up in Google Analytics after they have been sent by your app. If there's still nothing showing after 1 day, then you might need to check your code again.